# subset a dataframe using condition passed as string (subset dataframe dynamically)

Tags: r, dataframe

We can retrieve a subset of data-frame `df` where `col1`'s value is equal to 1 using the following code.

```
sub = df[df$col1==1,]
```

I want to subset a data-frame based on some conditions which are passed as strings

```
cond = "df$col1==1"
sub = df[cond, ]
```

The above code doesn't work. Is there any work around to achieve this? How to subset data-frame dynamically?

Comment: Try: `sub = df[eval(parse(text=cond)), ]`.

Comment: You're welcome. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
cond = "df$col1==1"
sub = df[eval(parse(text=cond)),]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As another option, you can use `filter_` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
sub = filter_(df, "col1 == 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[eval(parse(text="col1 ==1"))]
```